# ISSUE Cakephp 2.2 - Jquery Ajax Js->link save multiple entry id's on same page

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

Apologies if this question has been answered somewhere, I have tried to find it but to no avail

Cakephp is normally my friend, but it is driving me nuts right now. I am trying to create the option to vote an entry up on the same page where many other entries exist. I have done this a million times in Cake 1.3

**Issue:**
If I have 10 entries on a page (wrapped in unique divs), I can only 'score' the first entry, even though the entry_id is received correctly in the controller (FireBug) and debugging shows that $this->request->data is correct.Nevertheless Cake only saves 'score' for the first entry on the page and does NOT show any error message for the scores of other entries after clicking the link.

The UpdateALL action goes correct for ALL entries, only the SAVE action fails.

**Question:** Why does Cake not save scores for all entries on the page if I click the + link. Again, no error messages are thrown.

Controller:

```
public function score($id = null)
{
    if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
        if ($this->Entry->updateAll(array('Entry.score' => 'Entry.score+1'), array('Entry.id' => $id))) {
            $this->Entry->Score->create();
            $this->request->data['Score']['entry_id'] = $id;
            $this->request->data['Score']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Entry->Score->save($this->request->data)) {
                $total_scored = $this->Entry->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Entry.id' => $id)));
                $this->Entry->contain();
                $this->set('total_scored', $total_scored);
                if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
                    $this->render('_scored', 'ajax');
                } else {
                    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
 <div class="scoreButton-<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id'];?>">
 <?php if (((AuthComponent::user('id')) && ($entry['Entry']['user_id'] !== AuthComponent::user('id')))): ?>
            <p class="monster l20 t25 hover"><?php echo $this->Js->link('+','/entries/score/' . $entry['Entry']['id'] . '', array('update' => '.scored-' . $entry['Entry']['id'] . '', 'complete' => $this->Js->get('.scoreButton-' . $entry['Entry']['id'] . '')->effect('hide'))); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="scored-<?php echo $entry['Entry']['id'];?>"> </div>

        <?php endif;?>
        <?php if (!AuthComponent::user('id')): ?>
        <p class="monster grey l20 t25">+</p>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for the time being. It looks like a Cake bug and I will report it. The workaround is to save the score with a dummy entry_id (not visible to users) and update it to the right entry_id right after the save.

```
    public function score($id = null)
{
if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
    if ($this->Entry->updateAll(array('Entry.score' => 'Entry.score+1'), array('Entry.id' => $id))) {
        //$this->Entry->Score->create();
        $this->request->data['Score']['entry_id'] = '50458841-0000-0000-0000-1166a76fed09';
        $this->request->data['Score']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Entry->Score->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Entry->Score->updateAll(
                array('Score.Entry_id' => "'".$id."'"),
                array('Score.id' => $this->Entry->Score->id)
            );
            $total_scored = $this->Entry->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Entry.id' => $id)));
            $this->Entry->contain();
            $this->set('total_scored', $total_scored);
            if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
                $this->render('_scored', 'ajax');
            } else {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}